# Recyclerview onscrolllistener not working when setNestedScrollingEnabled to false

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I want to implement pagination with `recyclerView`, for this I add `addOnScrollListener` to the `recyclerView` but I am having trouble with `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` not working when I set `rvGridExplore.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

But when I remove `rvGridExplore.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` it is working fine,
I don't know how to handle this.

Here is code:

```
rvGridExplore = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvGridExplore);
        final GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(context,2);
       // rvGridExplore.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        rvGridExplore.setLayoutManager(glm);

       // final int visibleItemCount,totalCount,pastVisibleItems;
        rvGridExplore.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                Log.v("scrollll","state changed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy > 0) {
                    int totalCount = glm.getItemCount();
                    int visibleItemCount = glm.getChildCount();
                    int pastVisibleItems = glm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (loading) {
                        if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems) >= totalCount) {
                            Log.v("scroll","scrolled"+pastVisibleItems);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why do you need to call setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)?

Comment: it is under NestedScrollView which is under coordinator layout, if i remove this, Toolbar is not scrolling up

Comment: Wait, do you want the Toolbar to scroll up or do you want it not to scroll up?

Comment: i want to scroll up, and its working find when rvGridExplore.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: That doesn't make sense.... it should be the opposite.

Comment: its working fine, now problem is for OnScrolllistener

Comment: am also facing same issue...did you find any solution?

Comment: NO, i have not found yet

Comment: @AdnanAli did you found any solution?

Comment: Any one found the solution of OnScrolllistener?

Answer (score 8):

Do add setOnScrollChangeListner to your NestedScrollView

```
 nestedScrollview.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            if (scrollY == (v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight()))  {
               if(loading)
                onClick();
               loading=false;
            }
        }
    });
```

after loading data from server set boolean loading=true.

Answer (score 6):

This question may be old, but to help others who stumbled upon this problem, i would like to share what i did. I had to implement onScroll Listener to `recyclerview` to load data from server and to make some UI changes. And also needed swipeRefresh Layout for refreshing data.

This was my xml file structure,

```
-RelativeLayout

 -SwipeRefreshLayout

  -NestedScrollView

   -LinearLayout(Vertical)

    -Multiple views required
```

After this, to detect up and down scrolling i implemented setOnScrollListener to the NestedScrollView.

Normal usage of SwipeRefreshLayout to refresh data.

And to load more data i implemented the logic inside onScrollListener of NestedScrollingView.

```
if (scrollY == (v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight()))  {

    // Load More Data
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are recyclerView is embedded in any of the **NestedScrollView**, then you are supposed to attach the onScrollListener to NestedScrollView.

This will work!

```
if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
    final GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = (GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            if (scrollY == (v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight()))  {
                totalItemCount = gridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = gridLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!loading
                        && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    // End has been reached
                    // Do something
                    if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said in a comment to your question "
it is under NestedScrollView which is under coordinator layout, if i remove this, Toolbar is not scrolling up". **This is a mistake**.

I have found that you cannot have it both ways, the `CoordinatorLayout` behaviour breaks when you have a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView` to which you've added the behaviour. You need to use one or the other.

When you have a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView` it will work as long as you set `RecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`, but as you found out this means that the `OnScrollListener` is not called.

The only way for all components to work correctly is to remove the `NestedScrollView`, make sure you **do not set nesting scroll to false** and work from there. Otherwise the `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` events will not fire correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 : Create EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener**

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    public static String TAG = EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();

    // use your LayoutManager instead
    private LinearLayoutManager llm;

    public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager sglm) {
        this.llm = llm;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
            onScrolledToEnd();
        }
    }

    public abstract void onScrolledToEnd();
}
```

**Step 2: Apply scroll listener to recycler view.**

```
recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onScrolledToEnd() {
                Log.e("Position", "Last item reached");
                if (loadMore == true) {
                    // put your Load more code
                    // add 10 by 10 to tempList then notify changing in data
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: you mean i put the child class in constructor it will work ?
please read the question properly. my Listener is not working because of setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: than why you are putting nestedScrollingEnabled(false) ??

Comment: see the comments on question

Comment: i also do a pagination with this code like same situation as you

Comment: first put your layout.xml if you want proper answer!!

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ It is not working in the case of StaggeredGridLayoutManager ...Do u have any idea about it..Please help

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ .. I want  to load more functionality in my Straggered recyclview...Yet now i am facing the problem is that.. i am not getting the event to identify that user is reached at the bottom of the list OR not...Could u plz help me on this... I have also asked the question on SO..My question link is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930139/staggered-gridview-recycleview-with-load-more-functionality

Answer (score 0):

remove the nested scroll view use linear or relative layout instead of it as root element then you can write recyclerview.setNestedScrollEnabled(false);